# vagrant up isn't usable on this system

Tags: vagrant, homestead

Windows 10. Using Vagrant with VirtualBox. Laravel Homestead box.

I've been using vagrant for a while now, but starting today, whenever I run vagrant up I get this error message:

> Vagrant detected that VirtualBox appears installed on your system,
>   but calls to detect the version are returning empty. This is often
>   indicative of installation issues with VirtualBox. Please verify that
>   VirtualBox is properly installed. As a final verification, please run
>   the following command manually and verify a version is outputted:
>
> C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe --version

I have tried installing the latest version of VirtualBox with no success.

Answer (score 6):

Problem was ConEmu, the command line interface I use.

Just opened a plain and simple cmd, ran vagrant up and everything works.

More info: https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/323

Comment: There is a problem with ConEmu version 210304

Comment: Glad to know 5 years later it helped someone else, I don't even remember the problem lol.